# What are all the ways CouchDB reponses fail?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, express

I'm building a Node.js application on the express.js framework with CouchDB as a database. I'm utilizing CouchDB's session api for maintaining session state, and various databases for different sections of data.

On essentially every request my application code makes a request to Couch and then if there's an error (with Node) I can respond appropriately, by logging the error and redirecting to a 404 page or something like that. But if I get a CouchDB error, Node wouldn't consider it an error, it would consider that data. Now that's totally fine with me as long as CouchDB can only return this format:

```
{
  "error": "illegal_database_name",
  "reason": "Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter."
}
```

A JSON doc with two properties, error and reason. That's fine I can parse it and return the appropriate message; quite gracefully actually.

BUT! Is that all I can expect from CouchDB, or is there another way Couch might fail, that wouldn't yield a JSON doc with those two fields (properties)?

Comment: Why don't you just use nano like suggested on previous answers? Maybe even reading the source code? :) Relevant lines of code https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/nano.js#L280

Comment: I might. Read through some of the source code, looks great! Reading a book on web application security right now. Really interesting stuff. I think I've got a good handle on it though. How is nano from a security perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dscape's information of relying on the response codes is correct, and in most situations you will get an object with `error` and `reason`.  The bulk-document errors are the only place I can think of where neither of these will be true.  If just one document fails then you'll still get a 200, but you'll get the `error/reason` within the array element corresponding to the document that failed.  See [the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request) for more info on that.